# Why am i getting wrong ans(rather 2 different answers) when comparing 2 strings

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, g++

When normally comparing the string this way:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a = "yb";
    string b = "ya";
    cout<<(a>b);

    return 0;
}
```

result comes out `1`. Which is right.

But when performing the same operation in this way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<("yb">"ya");

    return 0;
}
```

result is coming out `0`.

How is this possible?

Comment: In the second case, you aren't comparing `std::string` objects but `const char*` pointers.

Comment: `("yb">"ya");` just compares two `const char*` pointers, not `std::string` instances. You may change that to `cout<<("yb"s>"ya"s);` to get it working as intended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Comparison of String Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450021/c-comparison-of-string-literals)

Answer (score 2):

`"yb"` and `"ya"` have type `char const[3]`; they are arrays located somewhere in the memory containing the chars in the string literal and the terminating 0 char.

When doing `("yb">"ya")` those objects decay to `char const*` and you're comparing pointers. Where the data is stored is compiler implementation defined and you cannot rely on the result.

To compare `std::string`s, you'd need to write

```
std::cout<<(std::string("yb")>std::string("ya"));
```

instead.