# C++ string comparison

Tags: c++, string, lexicographic

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    string s1("22"); 
    string s2("21"); 
    cout<<(s1 < s2)<<endl;
    cout<<("22" < "21")<<endl;
return 0; 
}
```

Try running the c++ code.

Why does the output give 0 and 1? and not the same answer. I might ask is s1 and "22" different, if so how?

Comment: why tag `c` ? c has no `std::string`

Comment: `"22"` is not a `std::string` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: `"22" < "21"` compares pointers. See [C++ Comparison of String Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450021/c-comparison-of-string-literals)

Comment: `"22"s < "21"s` will work because they're std::string. Similarly `"22"sv < "21"sv` should work, but `"22" < "21"` won't work as they're `const char[]`s

Comment: OT: you should also have `#include <string>` although is it obviously included by `<iostream>`.  Always include what you use.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Could you please explain more. I didn't get you

Comment: what do you not get? `"22"` is a string literal. `s1` is a `std::string`. Thats totally different types of objects with different `<`. As others said, `"11" < "22"` compares pointers not strings

Comment: `s1` and `s2` are of type `std::string`, and comparing them does a lexicographic comparison of the contents. `"22"` and `"21"` are string literals, which are each represented as a `const` array of three `char`s (`{'2', '2', '\0'}'` and `{'2', '1', '\0'}'`  respectively.  Comparing string literals actually compares the address of the first characters in both arrays, which is totally different from lexicographic comparison.   Since the two arrays are distinct objects, the result of comparing the addresses of their first characters is *unspecified* (getting `1` (or `true`) is NOT guaranteed).