# How lambda function in set algorithms in C++ really works?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am curious about how std algorithms interpret lambda expressions. In below example I am using std::set_difference algorithm for two maps. But the question is common for all algorithms vs comparison function.

```
    std::map<std::string, int> map1{ {"test1",1}, {"test2",2}, {"test3",3}, {"test4",4},{"wxyz5",10}};
    std::map<std::string, int> map2{ {"test1",2}, {"test2",3} };

    std::map<std::string, int> difference;

    std::set_difference(map1.begin(), map1.end(), map2.begin(), map2.end(), std::inserter(difference, difference.begin()), [](const auto& one, const auto& two) { return one.first < two.first; });
```

I am getting correct output , `{"test3",3}, {"test4",4},{"wxyz5",10}`.

question is, if the comparison function returns true will the first element be added to output ?

If that is the case ,  I tried this in lambda return `return one.first != two.first` it breaks with assertion `sequence not ordered`. Here I am expecting that if keys are not same in both the maps then , return true , and the first element should be added to output. but it is not working .

Probably my way of understanding how each algorithm interprets lambda expression is wrong. Can anyone please explain .

thanks.

Comment: `"wxyz5" < "test1"` compares pointers because both operands are actually **string literals** which decays to pointer to const char. See [C++ Comparison of String Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450021/c-comparison-of-string-literals)

Comment: The program has **undefined behavior** which means *anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely or make conclusions based on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.* **So the first step would to remove the UB from your program and then ask the question again.**

Comment: I would also recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that explains these things. Also we need a [mcve]

Comment: @user12002570 Thanks for the explanation . but the real question is not about why if and else if condition is not passing . I understood from your explanation that it compares pointers. the real question is , how to find the difference between two maps of <string , int>. and how the algorithm interprets the lambda ? if the given lambda function returns true , then that entry will be added to output ? I edited my question also .

Comment: *...and it breaks...*  What breaks?  Your code snippet didn't break for me.  I added the missing pieces, and it worked.  Possibly what broke is in the code you did not provide.  A [mcve] would be most helpful.

Comment: @sureshkumar This is why we ask for a [mcve]. Something that we can copy/paste into a compiler and reproduce the problem/issue.

Comment: The question has been edited to make sense now. It is no longer a duplicate of the one mentioned in the close votes. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Eljay probably you might have run the code in release mode . if you run it in debug mode , you will get assertion . I edited the question more to make sense

Comment: The comparison lambda is for *ordering*.  A `x != y` does not *order* the items.